# Write on MySQL master-master replication

Tags: mysql, master-master-replication

I have set up MySQL MM replication and they work well. I also know that it's not good to write simultaneously on both servers since it may cause inconsistency.

However, I wonder if I write on both servers but different databases (say write on the first server database A, and the 2nd one database B), then is it safer? Performance wise does it make sense to balance utilization of both servers?

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can go wrong with M-M.  Most of them are prevented by writing to only one of the Masters.

Since all writes must be performed by both Masters (and all Slaves), there is very little 'write scaling' to be achieved by dual-master.

If both Masters are in the same location (think: flood plain, earthquake fault, tornado alley), what is the advantage of M-M?

Comment: Advantages: Read scaling? Some insurance against downtime because of hardware failures?

Comment: @dbdemon - Yes, M-M gives some read scaling.  Yes, some HA, but not much if both are in the same location.  All types are rare; which ones "keep you awake at night"?